# Is that proof correct concerning a subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra

We have been given H which is subgroup of G, N which is normal subgroup of G.

HN={hn : h $\in$ H, n $\in$ N} show that is subgroup of G.

Im only not sure about closed under operation my prove:
$h_{1}n_{1}h_{2}n_{2} = h_{1}h_{2}h_{2}^{-1}n_{1}h_{2}n_{2}$

Ok we know $h_{1}h_{2} \in H$, $n_{2} \in N$,  but I'm no sure that $h_{2}^{-1}n_{1}h_{2} \in N$ ? because N is normal usually this looks $h_{2}n_{1}h_{2}^{-1}$ So its equal?

Comment: a pro**of** $\neq$ to pro**ve** (see the modification I have made in your title)

Comment: Thanks changed.

Comment: N normal subgroup of H?

Comment: N normal subgroup of G edited.

Comment: Looks pretty good, yes $h_2^{-1}n_1h_2$ is in $N$ because $N$ is normal. Since this holds for every $h_2\in H$, it implies the statement for $h_3=h_2^{-1}$

Comment: @Fakemistake but im not sure that $h_{2}^{-1}n_{1}h_{2} \in N$ do you know it's correct and why if it's is?

Comment: @Fakemistake but usually when $N$ is normal we know that $h_{2}n_{1}h_{2}^{-1}$ why can we change $h_{2}$  and $h_{2}^{-1}$

Comment: To be correct: the normality holds for all $h_2\in G$, but $H$ is a subset of $G$. So it holds for all $h_2\in H$.

Comment: Maybe you should think about, that it's not important in the definition of a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ to write $gng^{-1}$ or $g^{-1}ng$ because $g$ is arbitrary, so this holds for every $g\in G$. Is the question now answered?

Comment: Yes thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 0):

If $N \unlhd G $, we know that $\forall g \in G: gNg^{-1} \in N$. So pick a $h \in G$. Then, we have $hNh^{-1} \in N$. Now, do the same thing for $h^{-1} \in G$. Then $h^{-1}N(h^{-1})^{-1} \in N \iff h^{-1}Nh \in N$. Since we picked $h$ randomly, we can conclude that:

$$N \unlhd G \Rightarrow \forall h \in G:h^{-1}Nh \in N$$ 
(the other implication is true as well).